# Can IntelliSense Be Used to Print Out A Class Structure?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I'm often given classes to work with that have no documentation.

To get them to work, I rely upon Visual Studio's *IntelliSense*: I type the item in, hit the "dot" <kbd>.</kbd>, then transfer the displayed methods, parameters, and return types to a sheet of paper.

I'd like to move this process out of the Iron Age and into the 1990s.

I noticed someone else asked a question similar to this, but his question was for Java, so the solution was not applicable. Here it is for reference:

[How do I print the class structures in a jar file using the javap tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1171549/153923)

I'd like to iterate (some how) over the various classes, printing the names of these classes to a StringBuilder, then parse into all of the methods of each class, printing the method signatures to the StringBuilder class.

[image: screenshot of what I'd like to do]

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you're using a version of VS that supports extensions, you could install [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef), which can replace the built-in Solution Navigation with one that outlines all the fields, properties, methods, etc. in a class.

Comment: +1 for the Productivity Power Tools. In addition, if you want to examine .NET assemblies outside of VS, you can you tools like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/).

Comment: You can use reflection to do that. You could also use the "goto definition" feature of VS, or a decompiler like ILSpy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing full object graph using C# and reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443548/printing-full-object-graph-using-c-sharp-and-reflection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out ilspy - http://ilspy.net/

With that, you can browse a library (.dll) and get at what you need.  You can also do this in visual studio, sorta, by double clicking on the DLL in the solution explorer (if it's in your /bin/ just click 'show all files' button).  Try both and use the one with the best structure.

Comment: Awesome! And I thought this was going to be one of those questions with no responses.