# How to generically build a reference graph for an object

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a scenario where I need to recursively inspect all the references held by an object (regardless of whether it's public or private). The objects I need to inspect are very complicated and there are many different types so I'd prefer to write it generically if possible.

Something like this (just an example, the API is unimportant):

```
var myObject = new MyObject();
var graph = GetGraph(myObject);
foreach (var reference in graph.References)
{
    foreach (var subreference in reference.References)
    {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

**It doesn't need to handle circular references. In fact, if it blows up on a circular reference that would be just fine since this is what I'm trying to detect.** I'm guessing some clever reflection could do this, but I'm not very experienced with reflection. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be helped with a tool for this? http://www.amberfish.net/download.aspx  this is an assembly checker that visually showns all the references in a assembly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443548/printing-full-object-graph-using-c-sharp-and-reflection

Comment: Do you mean object references, or type references? Reflection is designed to return type information, not object information. It can, however, reveal information about private members; on the other hand, I am unclear if you want the types, or the data (or, possibly, both). If you want to walk an object tree looking for object references, you don't necessarily need reflection.

Comment: @MikeHofer I'm really interested in finding circular references in a complex reference graph. For example, A references B references C references A, where A is the same type and instance. B and C can be any type. I don't care about value types since they can't cause circular references.

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 I'm trying to find run-time circular references, i.e., same type and same instance. I think this tool builds a graph from the offline assembly right?

Answer (score 1):

Just out of the top of my head, I'd implement it something like this. First, create a Node-class that represents one object of the object-graph like so:

```
internal sealed class Node
{
    private readonly object _instance;
    private readonly List<Node> _referencedInstances;

    private static readonly Dictionary<object, Node> _Nodes = new Dictionary<object, Node>();

    public static Node CreateGraph(object instance)
    {
        ...
    }

    private static IEnumerable<object> FindReferencesOf(object instance)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The Dictionary can be used to store all created nodes and check for circular references, if you want to. (It's like using a fly-weight pattern).

The CreateGraph(object instance) can be called recursively to build the whole graph, but you may want to avoid recursion if your object-graphs become large.

The FindReferences-method will have to use reflection to search for all FieldInfo-objects of the instances type that are:

- public or non-public
- of a reference type and not a value type (I presume)

Hope you can do something with this.